# PHP require login to view

Tags: php, authentication

Okay, I have been playing with this for a while and I have gotten no where. I found that in order to block off a page (with PHP) if the user is not logged in, you need to have this code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['logged_in']))
{
    header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/login.php');
    exit;
}
?>
```

That's great, it worked. When I wasn't logged in, it blocked me off. The problem is that when I did log in, it still blocked me off. Here is the login.php code:

```
<?php
include("db.php");
session_start();
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // username and password sent from Form
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $password = md5($password); // Encrypted Password
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username='$username' and passcode='$password'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

    // If result matched $username and $password, table row must be 1 row
    if ($count == 1) {
        header("location: index.php");
    } else {
        $error = "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
    }
}
?>
<form action="login.php" method="post">
    <label>UserName :</label>
    <input type="text" name="username"/><br />
    <label>Password :</label>
    <input type="password" name="password"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value=" Login "/><br />
</form>
```

Now, I know that I am logging in through here because it redirects to the index, but the index then kicks me off. I feel as though the sessions may be considered different, but by now it is 1:30 in the morning and after hours of working on this, I gave up and decided to ask you. If you know what I am doing wrong, please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your session for logged in user in if condition you have. Check the modified code below.

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // username and password sent from Form
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $password = md5($password); // Encrypted Password
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username='$username' and passcode='$password'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

    // If result matched $username and $password, table row must be 1 row
    if ($count == 1) {
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = 'YES'; // put session value here 
        header("location: index.php");
    } else {
        $error = "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I knew I was missing something but wasn't quite sure what it was. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You aren't setting the session variable.

try this

```
      if($count==1)
    {
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = 1; //Or whatever makes it not empty
        header("location: index.php");
    }
```

Right now you are sending yourself back to the index with an empty session variable

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I knew I was missing something but wasn't quite sure what it was. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using **Mysql***

You need to have `session_start()` before `include` as Dainis said and you also need to set `$_SESSION['logged_in']=true;` or what ever you want after checking username ,password is correct.

```
<?php
session_start();
include("db.php");
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    // username and password sent from Form
    $username=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $password=md5($password); // Encrypted Password
    $sql="SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username='$username' and passcode='$password'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

    // If result matched $username and $password, table row must be 1 row
    if($count==1)
    {
        $_SESSION['logged_in']=true;

        header("location: index.php");

    }
    else
    {
        $error="Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I knew I was missing something but wasn't quite sure what it was. Thanks again!